# Mocha/Chai - Test to click an element only if it's present, displayed or exists

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js, chai

I've just start looking at implementing tests with Selenium using a Mocha/Chai framework & am struggling with a login function. I want to check an item is present/displayed & to click it if it is.

Currently my test waits on the page loading & I want something like the following, which currently doesn't work:

```js
var elementOnPage = driver.findElement(By.('elementId')).isDisplayed();
//var elementOnPage = driver.findElement(By.('elementId')).exist;

if(elementOnPage == true){
  driver.findElement(By.('elementId')).click();
  }
else{
  driver.findElement(By.('anotherElement')).click();
  }
```

I've also tried the commented out line above but neither seems to work. The code always seems to hit the 2nd part of the if statement before continuing. If the element I'm checking for is present then the test executes the next line but if it's not present then the test fails with a "NoSuchElementError: No such element".

I also didn't realise I could use stuff like exists(), isPresent() or isElementPresent() either.

Does anyone have any ideas or point me in the right direction? I'm quite new to this.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The return value of `isDisplayed` is a promise, but you treat it as a boolean.

You need to do something like:

```
driver.findElement(By.id('elementId')).isDisplayed().then(function (displayed) {
    if (displayed) {
        driver.findElement(By.id('elementId')).click();
    }
    else{
        driver.findElement(By.id('anotherElement')).click();
    }
});
```

Or more concisely:

```
driver.findElement(By.id('elementId')).isDisplayed().then(function (displayed) {
    driver.findElement(By.id(displayed ? 'elementId' : 'anotherElement')).click();
});
```

By the way `By.('elementId')` cannot work. I've assumed you meant `By.id('elementId')`.

Comment: Thanks for this, I actually started with something similar to this but assumed I was off the mark.

When I run it, the code works fine if the element I I'm checking for is displayed but if it's not then the test fails with the "NoSuchElementError: No such element" & points at the line above where the if statement starts.

Not sure why though to be honest.

Comment: If you are still having a problem, then you should ask a *new question* that contains much more details than what you have in your question here. There may be a timing issue like other folks have suspected but it is not clear whether there is such problem unless you show the HTML you are trying to manipulate. I **strongly** suggest you research the problem on SO before asking because timing issue questions have been asked and answered before. There's a high likelihood you'd ask a duplicate question.

Comment: I'm suggesting asking a new question because the community does not see in a good light edits that add new problems to a question that presented a clear problem in the first place after the question has been answered with answers that addressed the initial problem. (The community calls such questions "chameleon questions". See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)).